# How to access variables defined in ViewPartial (ascx page) to be used in normal View (aspx page) in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have some variables defined in partial view called (Partial1.ascx)

```
  string value1 = "value1";
  string value2 = "value2";
  int id = 7;
```

Now in ASPX page view, I want to use the above values. In my normal view (aspx page) I have like this:

```
  <%Html.RenderPartial("Partial1.ascx");%>

  <%=value1 %> becomes <%=value2 %> with his id which is <%=id %>
```

But the compiler throws error that the `value1`, `value2` and `id` is not defined.

How to use these variables ?

Have I to define a model (new one) and pass as parameter in `RenderPartial` function -> `<%Html.RenderPartial("Partial1.ascx", NewModel);%>` ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the `NewModel` in a code block like this on the in the view:

```
<% var newModel = new NewModel(); %>
```

In your partial view you assign the properties in a code block like this:

```
<%
  Model.Id = 2;
  Model.Test = "newString";
%>
```

Then you can access the properties on the original viewpage like this:

```
<p><%=newModel.Test %></p>
<p><%=newModel.Id %></p>
```